# Estimating the shape of the distribution of histogram

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, pdf-format

Here is the data:

data = {37., 76, 81, 81, 28, 29, 18, 18, 27, 44, 18, 17, 70, 87, 45,
32, 88, 20, 18, 44, 17, 51, 24, 37, 24, 21, 18, 18, 17, 44, 25,
16, 45, 31, 74, 38, 16, 35, 17, 44, 34, 27, 87, 25, 45, 24, 44, 73,
18., 44, 16, 16, 73, 17, 16, 51, 24, 16, 31, 44, 86, 19, 52, 35,
18, 18, 70, 17, 28, 44, 69, 65, 57, 46, 23, 18, 56, 16, 20, 44,
77, 18, 74, 26, 59, 28, 21, 21, 29, 44, 17, 33, 17, 17, 36, 42,
18, 76, 53, 44};

When it is plotted in a histogram, how to find its distribution overlaid on the histogram, and how to estimate the shape of the distribution?

Comment: Are you sampling from a continuous or discrete distribution?  In other words, is the measurement an integer or a rounded real number?  And is there some theoretical reason to expect a commonly used distribution?  This might be a better question for https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = {37., 76, 81, 81, 28, 29, 18, 18, 27, 44, 18, 17, 70, 87, 45, 
   32, 88, 20, 18, 44, 17, 51, 24, 37, 24, 21, 18, 18, 17, 44, 25, 16,
    45, 31, 74, 38, 16, 35, 17, 44, 34, 27, 87, 25, 45, 24, 44, 73, 
   18., 44, 16, 16, 73, 17, 16, 51, 24, 16, 31, 44, 86, 19, 52, 35, 
   18, 18, 70, 17, 28, 44, 69, 65, 57, 46, 23, 18, 56, 16, 20, 44, 77,
    18, 74, 26, 59, 28, 21, 21, 29, 44, 17, 33, 17, 17, 36, 42, 18, 
   76, 53, 44};

distr = {HistogramDistribution,
   SmoothKernelDistribution,
   EstimatedDistribution[#,
     HalfNormalDistribution[a]] &,
   EstimatedDistribution[#,
     RiceDistribution[a, b]] &};

Column[Show[
    Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"],
    Plot[PDF[#[data], x], {x, 0, 100}],
    PlotLabel ->
     (# /. (EstimatedDistribution[_, d_] &) :> d),
    ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ distr]
```

[image]

Comment: @How to know which one describe it the best ?

Comment: Use [`DistributionFitTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionFitTest.html); however, that are a multitude of possible distributions that you could use. You should start by analyzing the process that is generating the data to determine what the theoretical distribution should be. Then use [`EstimatedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EstimatedDistribution.html) to find the best fit.